# self.context.$implicit.find is not a function Angular2 Forms

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am Upgrading Angular2 project from `2.0.0-rc.4` to `2.4.0` , while Upgradtion i have faced this error in Forms

> self.context.$implicit.find is not a function

i am using code like this:

```
<div formArrayName="pricing_details" *ngFor="let pricingDetails of myForm.controls.pricing_details.controls">

  <div *ngFor="let priceModifier of pricingDetails.find('pricing_modifiers').controls">
    ....
  </div>

</div>
```

Where `.find()` is used to find control name from the form array, it seems like `.find()` is deprecated now,

anybody here knows what is the alternate for this now in `Angular2 2.4.0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`AbstractControl#get()`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html#!#get-anchor)

```
<div *ngFor="let priceModifier of
pricingDetails.get('pricing_modifiers').controls"> .... </div>
```